# How to create signed x509certificate with a private key using a self signed certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

What I'd like to do is create a valid certificate to sign an electronic document. This requires a x509Certificate2 object with a private key.  What I cant figure out is how to create a signed certificate with a private key, using a CA certificate that I created.

If possible, I would like to do this with .Net code only (I am using 4.7.2).

The code that I have creates a valid CA certificate with a private key, however, the child certificate does not have a private key, thus cannot be used to sign electronic documents.

Heres the code that I have now...

```
        private void CreateCerts()
        {
            const string issuerName = "Issuer";
            const string signerName = "Signer";

            var root = GetCertificate(issuerName, StoreName.AuthRoot);

            if (root == null)
            {
                root = CreateRoot(issuerName);
            }

            var signer = GetCertificate(signerName, StoreName.My);

            if (signer == null)
            {
                signer = CreateSigner(root, signerName);
            }
        }

        private X509Certificate2 CreateSigner(X509Certificate2 root, string name)
        {
            X509Certificate2 signer = null;
            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
            {

                CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
                    $"CN={name}",
                    rsa,
                    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

                req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509KeyUsageExtension(
                        X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation,
                        false));

                req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                        new OidCollection
                        {
                            new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8")
                        },
                        true));

                req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(req.PublicKey, false));

                using (X509Certificate2 cert = req.Create(
                    root,
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(90),
                    new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }))
                {

                    using (var password = new SecureString())
                    {
                        password.AppendChar('P');
                        password.AppendChar('W');

                        var childExport = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);

                        signer = new X509Certificate2(childExport, password);

                        AddCertToStore(signer, StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                    }
                }
            }

            return signer;
        }

        private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string commonName, StoreName storeName)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            // Look for a certificate in the local machine store.
            // We will search for a certificate that has a CN (common name) that matches
            // the currently logged-in user.
            using (var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
                {
                    var subjectNames = cert.SubjectName.Name.Split(',');
                    foreach (var subjectName in subjectNames)
                    {
                        if (subjectName.Equals($"CN={commonName}"))
                        {
                            certificate = cert;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (certificate != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return certificate;
        }

        private X509Certificate2 CreateRoot(string name)
        {
            X509Certificate2 root = null;

            using (RSA parent = RSA.Create(4096))
            {
                CertificateRequest parentReq = new CertificateRequest(
                    $"CN={name}",
                    parent,
                    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, true));

                parentReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                    new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(parentReq.PublicKey, false));

                using (X509Certificate2 parentCert = parentReq.CreateSelfSigned(
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-45),
                    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365)))
                {
                    using (var password = new SecureString())
                    {
                        password.AppendChar('P');
                        password.AppendChar('W');

                        var export = parentCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);
                        root = new X509Certificate2(export, password);

                        AddCertToStore(root, StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                    }
                }
            }

            return root;
        }

        private void AddCertToStore(X509Certificate2 cert, StoreName name, StoreLocation location)
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(name, location))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                store.Add(cert);

                store.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you get this worked? share the fix here.

Answer (score 11):

Creating a certificate from another certificate treats the input key as if it was a public-key only (in fact, it'll accept the PublicKey type in the constructor).

If you want to mate it with a private key, use the CopyWithPrivateKey (extension) method:

```
using (X509Certificate2 cert = req.Create(
    root,
    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(90),
    new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }))
{
    using (X509Certificate2 certWithKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how to use CertificateRequest without private key.
Since the private key is in the HSM we only have public key. there is an overload that takes PublicKey but how do you construct it?

Comment: The RSA/ECDsa/etc classes can be either public only or public+private. If you already know how to sign or verify using the HSM, that would be the basis of a new question, if you haven’t even gotten that far, that would be your first step.